# My game is crashing after comes back from GameOverScene

Tags: ios, swift, crash, sprite-kit

I'm creating my first Game and it crashes after come back from GameOverScene. This are the part that gives me the error:

```
//  GameScene.swift
//  Test_Crash_1


import SpriteKit

struct global {

    static var wheelRotPlat2 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 400)
    static var button : SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode()
    static var actualPlayer : String = String()
    static let btnNextPlayer = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 70)
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    deinit {
        print("The GameScene has been removed from memory")
    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let buttonDice = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: (CGSizeMake(40,40)), cornerRadius: 5)
        global.button = buttonDice
        global.button.position = CGPoint(x: (CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-400), y:(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-350))
        global.button.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 1.0, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.8)
        global.button.name = "button"
        global.button.zPosition = 1
        addChild(global.button)

        global.wheelRotPlat2.addChild(global.btnNextPlayer)
        global.btnNextPlayer.name = "btnNextPlayer"
    } // end didMoveToView


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        //func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches //as!  Set<UITouch>
        let location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (node.name == "button") {

            self.removeAllActions()
            self.removeAllChildren()

            let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
            let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, player: global.actualPlayer)
            self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)

        }
    } // End func touchesBegan

} // end GameScene
```

And the GameOverScene file:

```
//  GameOverScene.swift
//  Test_Crash_1



import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    init(size: CGSize, player: String) {

        super.init(size: size)

        backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0),
            SKAction.runBlock() {


                let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
                let scene = GameScene(size: size)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)

            }
        ]))

    } // end init(size


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
} // end GameOverScene
```

The error is well the known:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  SKShapeNode  name:'btnNextPlayer'
```

This example has just a green button that takes me to the GameOverScene. When it returns the game crashes.

I don't understand why it happens in this case.
Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Aside from KnightOfDragon's answer, and my comment on his question, you have a retain cycle in GameOverScene. You can't use just like that self inside a closure. You should use weak or unowned self. Search SO about that...

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you what is happening, you are adding a node to another node, but the node already has a parent.  This is why using globals is a bad idea and should almost never be used.  You have a button that is global.  It is attached to GameScene, lets call GameScene1.  You then call Gameover.  Now you call a new GameScene, called GameScene2.  Since you are not managing your memory correctly because of things like global variables, GameScene1 still exists.  Well button is still attached to GameScene1, so when you try to add it to GameScene2, XCode says "No, this node has a parent, go fix yo stuff".  Try to not use global data, and you should see less problems like this.

Edit: 
As @Whirlwind pointed out,  the issue is in the global item `global.wheelRotPlat2` that is causing the problem.

`global.wheelRotPlat2.addChild(global.btnNextPlayer)` is being called every time a `GameScene` is moved to a view,  and since you never remove the `btnNextPlayer` from its parent when you kill your 1st Scene,  when you create your 2nd Scene,  the `global.btnNextPlayer` will try to reattach to the same exact parent again (global.wheelRotPlat2),  which is causing your problem.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon In general, what you are saying is true. But in this case, if you look closely, the button is not added to the scene. It is added to another node (wheelRotPlat2), which is not added to the scene as well. So even if scene is deallocated correctly, in this case, the same problem will occur.  I can write an answer to explain everything, but I am pretty much sure that you understand what I am saying. Also, you have my upvote because you are right in general and those are good practices.

Comment: What are you talking about? addChild(global.button) is in the didmovetoview

Comment: Oh damn it, lol his code is way to confusing LOL. He made a local in that case

Comment: @KnightOfDragon That button (global.button) is added to the scene, and its parent property will be set to nil on scene's deinit. The problem is related to another node (btnNextPlayer). That is what I am talking about.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Game scene will be deallocated properly in this case, and the global.button.parent property will be set to nil on GameScene's deinit. Globals are problem here, not a memory management and retain cycles.

Comment: When I first saw this, I thought I saw that the button was being added to the global node,  that is why I thought the scene was still being retained. Globals is a form of memory management, or lack there of lol.  As for the retain cycle, yes that also needs to be fixed, which is a different issue that would also not allow the scene to deinit.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. This is my first project and I will read about what you say and find a way to modify my code.
Thank you again Knight0fDragon and Whirlwind.

Comment: Thank You again guys, but now I'm back to my inicial problem. I created this struct "global" to be able to access my nodes from any part of my code. 
Without this struct, how can I access my node's properties from outside GameScene?
Let's say I have a function below GameScene, and I want to change a node's color, how can I do it? "childNodeWithName" doesn't work outside of GameScene...

Comment: what do you mean by access outside of GameScene?  I am confused because after this you say below GameScene,  Do you keep your classes in separate files?

Comment: I keep my functions in separate files, and I need access my nodes properties from there.

Comment: I do not know how much more I can help you then,  sounds like you have an organization problem going on here, but without seeing this project and how it is laid out, I can't help you anymore